# Segmentation fault when adding shared_ptr to list

Tags: qt, scope, stl, shared-ptr

Let me explain. In this method I'm trying to push new item to list.

```
spContainer ObjectsManager::createContainer(QStringList data, QVector2D onMapPosition) {
    spContainer new_container (new Container());
    new_container->setData(data);
    new_container->setPosistion(onMapPosition);
    containers.push_back(new_container);

    emit containerAdd(new_container->toQVariantMap());

    return new_container;
}
```

`spContainer` is a typedef:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Container> spContainer;
```

`containers` is a std::list

```
class ObjectsManager : public QObject {
...
public:
    spContainer createContainer(QStringList data, QVector2D onMapPosition);
...

private: 
    std::list<spContainer> containers;
};
```

The same error while using `QList` or `QVector`.
It's very strange, because if I will add to method new QList and try to push pointer into container...

```
spContainer ObjectsManager::createContainer(QStringList data, QVector2D onMapPosition) {
    spContainer new_container (new Container());
    new_container->setData(data);
    new_container->setPosistion(onMapPosition);
    QList<spContainer> conts;
    conts.push_back(new_container);
    //containers.push_back(new_container);

    emit containerAdd(new_container->toQVariantMap());

    return new_container;
}
```

It will work fine!

WAT? What the difference?! Can someone explain me what's going on?

Comment: Your test doesn't really demonstrate that QList (conts) works and std::list (containers) doesn't Work. Since they don't have the same scope.

Comment: @basslo thanks for feedback. You are right! Method wasn't be able to use std::list, because it was in uninitialized object's scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!
The problem was that I call the method of uninitialized object!

the fix is:

```
_objManager = spObjectsManager (new ObjectsManager);
_objManager->createContainer(data);
```